# XML file doesn't contian reference to Sharepoint collapsible sections

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, xml, collapsible-sections

I have been using `Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Out C:\file.xml -IncludeAllClientSidePages` to get the xml out but I have noticed that the pages which contains collapsible section doesn't collapsible when I `Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate`. There is nothing in the xml that has reference to the section being collapsible.Is there way I can extract the collapsible sections details so when I recreate the page it is there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same problem (using PnP.PowerShell 1.6.0): when getting the template from a page with collapsible sections, they won't show up in the XML, just their content. So it is not possible to provision a SiteDesign with these sections from template!

It would be nice if there was some reaction on this problem…

Comment: I have just updated to PnP.PowerShell 1.9.0, but it still does not work.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/118817)